# How to join two SQL tables to Excel and form an additional field

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel

### Goal

I want to connect my SQL tables `Articles` and `Providers` to an Excel sheet. Using those tables, I want to display an additional field in the Articles Excel sheet which will be `ExchangeType`. The exchange type field will determine if the current `Articles` cost is in US or Canadian dollars using a code field in the `Providers` table.

I currently do this with my VB.Net program which displays it like so:

[image: Exchange Type].

For English/French refrence, Coût ($) is Cost, Fournisseur is Provider and Taux is my Exchange Type (either US or CND).

---

### Current Situation

I currently display these fields in VB.Net quite easily. In the Providers table we have a column named "Code". If a code entry in the Providers Table starts with "1" we determine it as "US", else it is "CND". For example:

```
If ProviderRow.Code.StartsWith("1") Then
    obj.ExchangeType = "US"
Else
    obj.ExchangeType = "CND"
End If
```

These two tables are also in Excel by connecting them to the SQL tables.

Keep in mind, the property `ExchangeType` is a custom property that I created and assign these values to (it doesn't exist in the database). I am able to join the `Articles` and `Providers` table together because of the `FK_Provider` foreign key in my Articles Table.

[image: Articles Table can easily connect to Providers using the foreign key]

---

### Problem

I have no idea how to create a  custom field `ExchangeType` in Excel using those two tables. This is where I need help. **How do I create the custom field ExchangeType (in the Articles Excel sheet)** using two tables where the value must be either "US" or "CND" depending on the `Providers.Code.StartsWith("1") = True`.

Articles:

[image: Articles Table]

Providers:

[image: Providers Table]

Is it possible to do with Excel?

Comment: Can you Join the tables and create the needed column in SQL and us that as a source for your Excel table?